# Should I use a function pointer to select implementation in the constructor?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

The function pointer tutorials contain an [example of how to replace a switch statement by function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#why).

I have different algorithms which I would like to select in the constructor. 
My current implementation basically looks like this

```
// Constructor:
MyClass::MyClass(double *data) 
    : specialCase1(false), specialCase2(false), data_(data) {
  if (checkData1(data)) specialCase1 = true;
  else if (checkData2(data)) specialCase2 = true;
}
// Function:
double MyClass::work() {
  if (specialCase1) return workSpecialCase1();
  else if (specialCase2) return workSpecialCase2();
  // ... do work ...
}
```

The work function is called *a lot*, therefore I am looking into ways to optimize. In principle I could add a function pointer member to the class 'double (*selectedWorkFunc)()' and then change the work function to

```
 double MyClass::work() {
   return selectedWorkFunc()
}
```

In general, can I expect a performance gain by using the function pointer to avoid the the if statements in the work function?

Comment: Benchmark it and find out. With any luck maybe your compiler can inline selectedWorkFunc, but you won't know for sure until you try it out.

Comment: How much work is done in `workSpecialCase1()`? If it is sufficiently large, the if/else won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer : no.  'If' statements take a negligible amount of time on a modern, high-speed, pipelined processor.  Whatever takes a long time in this work function, it is not the if statement (and you should benchmark / profile to find out what is taking the time - it's a much more productive approach than speculative optimisation).

Answer (score 0):

After studying this [manual on c++ optimization](http://agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf), I would like to add some more infomation why the above idea will probably not work.

Since the bool value is selected on construction, the branch choosen will never change.

> A branch instruction takes typically 0 - 2 clock cycles in the case that the microprocessor 
>   has made the right prediction. The time it takes to recover from a branch misprediction is 
>   approximately 12 - 25 clock cycles, depending on the processor. This is called the branch 
>   misprediction penalty.

Function pointer evaluation takes longer than that:

> Calling a function through a function pointer typically takes a few clock cycles more than 
>   calling the function directly if the target address can be predicted.